# node js: unable to return value from a function

Tags: javascript, database, database-connection

I am not able to understand how i can get return value from a function in node js. Please find the code is below (I am able to get the results of the query in the console log but not able to find ow to return that value and store it into any variable after calling the function)

Call to the function main:

```
dbConnection("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","50000","select xxx,xxx,CURRENCY from xxx where AccountID='85433333'")
```

Function to setup database connection:

```
function dbConnection(dbname,hostname,UserID,Password,Port,query,callback)
{
      var ibmdb = require('ibm_db');
      ibmdb.open("DATABASE="+dbname+";HOSTNAME="+hostname+";UID="+UserID+";PWD="+Password+";PORT="+Port+";PROTOCOL=TCPIP", function (err,conn)
      {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
          var a= executeQuery(conn,query,function(err,data)
          {
            return data
          });
      });
}
```

Function to execute the query:

```
function executeQuery(conn,query,cb)
{
    conn.query(query, function (err, data)
    {
        if (err) console.log(err,data);
        else
            console.log(data);
    });
    //return callback(data);
};
```

Comment: you can't return value from callback. this is asynchronous scenario

Comment: if i want to make it non asynchronous how can i do it , please let me know

Comment: Remember, that node JS is asynchronous.
If you want to get the data returned, you can create a `promise`. Then if there is a result from your query, you set your promise to resolve!
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/async-functions

Answer (score 0):

That's an async function, so you need to use callback to return like the following. And invoke the call like

```
dbConnection("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx","50000","select xxx,xxx,CURRENCY from xxx where AccountID='85433333'", function(err, data) {
    console.log(data)
})

function dbConnection(dbname,hostname,UserID,Password,Port,query,callback)
{
  var ibmdb = require('ibm_db');
      ibmdb.open("DATABASE="+dbname+";HOSTNAME="+hostname+";UID="+UserID+";PWD="+Passw    ord+";PORT="+Port+";PROTOCOL=TCPIP", function (err,conn)
  {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      var a= executeQuery(conn,query,function(err,data)
      {
        callback(err, data)
      });
  });
}
```